# All canvas methods that change the canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd like to determine a list of all of the methods that have the ability to directly change an HTML5 canvas image. So far my list consists of `fillRect`, `stroke`, `putImageData` but I am sure I am missing some.

Answer (score 1):

I guess many of these, you can try them out and finish the list:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames( CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype );

["putImageData",
"rect",
"setLineJoin",
"clearShadow",
"isPointInPath",
"strokeRect",
"createRadialGradient",
"drawImage",
"measureText",
"translate",
"setLineCap",
"arc",
"fillRect",
"setTransform",
"stroke",
"drawImageFromRect",
"setFillColor",
"createPattern",
"setAlpha",
"setShadow",
"strokeText",
"createLinearGradient",
"setCompositeOperation",
"fill",
"transform",
"rotate",
"quadraticCurveTo",
"setMiterLimit",
"clip",
"scale",
"arcTo",
"clearRect",
"bezierCurveTo",
"fillText",
"restore"]
```

Comment: thanks, although yeah, as you stated a good number of them won't be directly changing the canvas image

Comment: @user730569 figuring that out is only matter of googling the methods or trying them out or looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D... which is fit task for you since you are the one who cares about this information, don't you think? ;p